# What is the fastest way to get input in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, input, io

Right now I am using sys.stdin.readline() but I am curious if it's considered slow to use map(int,sys.stdin.readline()) or if it makes sense to do something like "for item in sys.stdin" or something else (for mass input).

Comment: i am just asking. what's wrong with `input()` ?

Comment: @mbcoder `input()` is for prompting the user to type something in.  The OP presumably wants to pipe in data from a file or some other source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly reading from standard input is the "fastest" you can get if the data is streamed to your program via stdin. Both of your outlines approaches do this. Personally, I prefer the

```
for line in sys.stdin
    process(line)
```

idiom, if this is applicable in your case. In any case, with reading directly from standard input you can theoretically process gigabytes of data per second, the bottleneck of your work flow likely is somewhere else.

The main difference you can create here between different approaches is that in one class of cases you may read the entire input into memory before processing it, while in the other class of approaches you process the input piece-wise on the fly. Depending on the size of your overall input this difference might be relevant or not.